# How to draw fade out text on a custom TGraphicControl?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I would like to draw fade-out text on a TGraphicControl, something like the tabs on Google Chrome, when there isn't enough space to display the whole text on the Canvas.

So instead of displaying elipsis text (which I know how to do), I want it to fade out like this: [image: delphi]

The TGraphicControl needs to have transparent option like TCustomLabel (`ControlStyle - [csOpaque]`).

---

This is probably an easy task with GDIPlus but I need to use pure GDI.

---

I also try to study the code of [TGradText v.1.0](http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=181) (Direct [download](http://www.torry.net/vcl/misceff/scrollingtext/gradtext.zip)) which does (almost) exactly what I need - it can draw transparent text but the result looks very bad and not smooth. I guess it's because it makes a pmCopy mask for this task.

---

Here is the code I wrote based on Andreas Rejbrand answer. I used a PaintBox over a TImage and prerendered the backgound:

```
type
  TParentControl = class(TWinControl);

{ This procedure is copied from RxLibrary VCLUtils }  
procedure CopyParentImage(Control: TControl; Dest: TCanvas);
var
  I, Count, X, Y, SaveIndex: Integer;
  DC: HDC;
  R, SelfR, CtlR: TRect;
begin
  if (Control = nil) or (Control.Parent = nil) then Exit;
  Count := Control.Parent.ControlCount;
  DC := Dest.Handle;
  with Control.Parent do ControlState := ControlState + [csPaintCopy];
  try
    with Control do
    begin
      SelfR := Bounds(Left, Top, Width, Height);
      X := -Left; Y := -Top;
    end;
    { Copy parent control image }
    SaveIndex := SaveDC(DC);
    try
      SetViewportOrgEx(DC, X, Y, nil);
      IntersectClipRect(DC, 0, 0, Control.Parent.ClientWidth,
        Control.Parent.ClientHeight);
      with TParentControl(Control.Parent) do
      begin
        Perform(WM_ERASEBKGND, DC, 0);
        PaintWindow(DC);
      end;
    finally
      RestoreDC(DC, SaveIndex);
    end;
    { Copy images of graphic controls }
    for I := 0 to Count - 1 do begin
      if Control.Parent.Controls[I] = Control then Break
      else if (Control.Parent.Controls[I] <> nil) and
        (Control.Parent.Controls[I] is TGraphicControl) then
      begin
        with TGraphicControl(Control.Parent.Controls[I]) do begin
          CtlR := Bounds(Left, Top, Width, Height);
          if Bool(IntersectRect(R, SelfR, CtlR)) and Visible then begin
            ControlState := ControlState + [csPaintCopy];
            SaveIndex := SaveDC(DC);
            try
              SetViewportOrgEx(DC, Left + X, Top + Y, nil);
              IntersectClipRect(DC, 0, 0, Width, Height);
              Perform(WM_PAINT, DC, 0);
            finally
              RestoreDC(DC, SaveIndex);
              ControlState := ControlState - [csPaintCopy];
            end;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    with Control.Parent do ControlState := ControlState - [csPaintCopy];
  end;
end;

type
  PRGB32Array = ^TRGB32Array;
  TRGB32Array = packed array[0..MaxInt div SizeOf(TRGBQuad)-1] of TRGBQuad;

procedure FadeBMToWhite(Bitmap: TBitmap);
var
  w, h: integer;
  y: Integer;
  sl: PRGB32Array;
  x: Integer;
begin
  Bitmap.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
  w := Bitmap.Width;
  h := Bitmap.Height;
  for y := 0 to h - 1  do
  begin
    sl := Bitmap.ScanLine[y];
    for x := 0 to w - 1 do
      with sl[x] do
      begin
        rgbBlue := rgbBlue + x * ($FF - rgbBlue) div w;
        rgbGreen := rgbGreen + x * ($FF - rgbGreen) div w;
        rgbRed := rgbRed + x * ($FF - rgbRed) div w;
      end;
  end;
end;

procedure FadeLastNpx(Canvas: TCanvas; N: Integer; ClientWidth, ClientHeight: Integer);
var
  bm: TBitmap;
begin
  bm := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    bm.Width := N;
    bm.Height := ClientHeight;
    BitBlt(bm.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, N, ClientHeight,
      Canvas.Handle, ClientWidth - N, 0, SRCCOPY);
    FadeBMToWhite(bm);
    BitBlt(Canvas.Handle, ClientWidth - N, 0, N, ClientHeight,
      bm.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
  finally
    bm.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
var
  w: integer;
  r: TRect;
  S: string;
  CurScreen: TBitmap; // offscreen bitmap to speed things up
begin
  with PaintBox1 do
  begin
    CurScreen := TBitmap.Create;
    CurScreen.Width := Width;
    CurScreen.Height := Height;
    CopyParentImage(PaintBox1, CurScreen.Canvas);

    with CurScreen do
    begin
      Canvas.Font.Assign(PaintBox1.Font);

      S := 'This is a string.';
      Canvas.Font.Size := 20;
      w := Canvas.TextWidth(S);
      r := ClientRect;

      Canvas.FrameRect(r); // for testing
      Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear; 
      DrawText(Canvas.Handle, PChar(S), Length(S), r, DT_SINGLELINE or DT_VCENTER);
      if w > ClientWidth then
        FadeLastNpx(Canvas, 50, ClientWidth, ClientHeight);
    end; // with CurScreen

    Canvas.Draw(0, 0, CurScreen);
  end; // with PaintBox1

  CurScreen.Free;
end;
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the right egde of the background is also faded. it looks nice. but I wonder if *only the text* could be faded with TLama sugeestion?

Comment: Theoretically this is a very simple task, but I think you have to do it manually, since I believe there is no standard Win32 function for this. So, the obvious question is what you have tried, and why it didn't work. After all, on this site you aren't really supposed to ask others to do the job for you.

Comment: @Andreas, This might look like "a very simple task" to you, but not to me. If it's so simple why dont you just answer? I hate to be rude, but the "what you have tried" in the Delphi group seems to be the main answers here :/ I can read the TCustomLabel source, I'm not that dumb. I can add the DT_END_ELLIPSIS but I just cant figure out a way to do what I need. I not an API/GDI expert. My speciality is DB applications. Finally If I knew that answer I would have asked it in the first place.

Comment: @All close-voters: please [don't confuse effortless with unanswerable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210840/162538). Downvote instead, it's free. But this is a great question!

Comment: Well, to your edit. With a pure GDI I think you'll have a hard work. Let's say you'd have a temporary 32-bit bitmap. On that you'll render the text and change the alpha channel values for the right side of that bitmap to fade out. Problem ? The bitmap won't be transparent...

Comment: @TLama, I agree. I look at rkSmartTabs and ChromeTabs. they do that with GDIPlus: not very complicated. but I really don't want to do depend on GDIPlus for this small task. If this cannt be done at all, I'll drop this.

Comment: [Just for the record, I didn't downvote. I only tried to explain the downvotes.]

Comment: @Vlad, if you'll be able to prerender what's behind your control to that 32-bit temporary bitmap, you can then simply render the text and fade the whole result out by modifying alpha channel (like shown in Andreas' answer). Otherwise, you'd need to make a transparent bitmap, render the text with opaqueness (that's the hard part) and then fade the right side out.

Comment: @TLama, I can prerender the backround first. however the result look the same. I'll post my code. please tell me if this is the effect you were thinking about...

Comment: @Vlad, sorry, I missed that Andreas were fading to white in the original answer. In his update he's using some sort of fade out premultiplication.

Comment: There is [`this question`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20582226/960757) which asked for the same effect in GDI+ (just to make this question linked with the other one).

Comment: @TLama, your link points to my question.

Comment: Infinite loop :) There is [`this question`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28124914/960757) which asked for the same effect in GDI+ (just to make this question linked with the other one).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
unit Unit5;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs;

type
  TForm5 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormResize(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure FadeLast50px;
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form5: TForm5;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

type
  PRGB32Array = ^TRGB32Array;
  TRGB32Array = packed array[0..MaxInt div SizeOf(TRGBQuad)-1] of TRGBQuad;

procedure FadeBMToWhite(Bitmap: TBitmap);
var
  w, h: integer;
  y: Integer;
  sl: PRGB32Array;
  x: Integer;
begin
  Bitmap.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
  w := Bitmap.Width;
  h := Bitmap.Height;
  for y := 0 to h - 1 do
  begin
    sl := Bitmap.ScanLine[y];
    for x := 0 to w - 1 do
      with sl[x] do
      begin
        rgbBlue := rgbBlue + x * ($FF - rgbBlue) div w;
        rgbGreen := rgbGreen + x * ($FF - rgbGreen) div w;
        rgbRed := rgbRed + x * ($FF - rgbRed) div w;
      end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm5.FadeLast50px;
var
  bm: TBitmap;
begin
  bm := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    bm.SetSize(50, ClientHeight);
    BitBlt(bm.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, 50, ClientHeight,
      Canvas.Handle, ClientWidth - 50, 0, SRCCOPY);
    FadeBMToWhite(bm);
    BitBlt(Canvas.Handle, ClientWidth - 50, 0, 50, ClientHeight,
      bm.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
  finally
    bm.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm5.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
const
  S = 'This is a string.';
var
  w: integer;
  r: TRect;
begin
  Canvas.Font.Size := 20;
  w := Canvas.TextWidth(S);
  r := ClientRect;
  DrawText(Canvas.Handle, S, Length(S), r, DT_SINGLELINE or DT_VCENTER);
  if w > ClientWidth then
    FadeLast50px;
end;

procedure TForm5.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Invalidate;
end;

end.
```

[image: Screenshot]

[Compiled demo EXE](https://privat.rejbrand.se/fadestr.exe)

---

**Update**

Here's a simple experiment with a background:

```
unit Unit5;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs;

type
  TForm5 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormResize(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form5: TForm5;
  bk: TBitmap;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

const
  BLENDWIDTH = 100;

type
  PRGB32Array = ^TRGB32Array;
  TRGB32Array = packed array[0..MaxInt div SizeOf(TRGBQuad)-1] of TRGBQuad;

procedure FadeBM(Bitmap: TBitmap);
var
  w, h: integer;
  y: Integer;
  sl: PRGB32Array;
  x: Integer;
begin
  Bitmap.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
  w := Bitmap.Width;
  h := Bitmap.Height;
  for y := 0 to h - 1 do
  begin
    sl := Bitmap.ScanLine[y];
    for x := 0 to w - 1 do
      with sl[x] do
      begin
        rgbReserved := Round(255*x/w);
        rgbRed := rgbRed * rgbReserved div 255;
        rgbGreen := rgbGreen * rgbReserved div 255;
        rgbBlue := rgbBlue * rgbReserved div 255;
      end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm5.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  bk := TBitmap.Create;
  with TOpenDialog.Create(nil) do
    try
      Filter := 'Windows Bitmap|*.bmp';
      if Execute then
        bk.LoadFromFile(FileName)
    finally
      Free;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm5.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
const
  S = 'This is a string.';
var
  w: integer;
  r: TRect;
  bf: TBlendFunction;
  bk2: TBitmap;
begin
  // Draw backgrond
  BitBlt(Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, ClientWidth, ClientHeight, Bk.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
  // Draw text
  Canvas.Font.Size := 20;
  Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
  w := Canvas.TextWidth(S);
  r := ClientRect;
  DrawText(Canvas.Handle, S, Length(S), r, DT_SINGLELINE or DT_VCENTER);
  if w > ClientWidth then
  begin
    bk2 := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      bk2.SetSize(BLENDWIDTH, ClientHeight);
      BitBlt(bk2.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, BLENDWIDTH, ClientHeight, Bk.Canvas.Handle, ClientWidth - BLENDWIDTH, 0, SRCCOPY);
      FadeBM(bk2);
      bf.BlendOp := AC_SRC_OVER;
      bf.BlendFlags := 0;
      bf.SourceConstantAlpha := 255;
      bf.AlphaFormat := AC_SRC_ALPHA;
      Windows.AlphaBlend(Canvas.Handle, ClientWidth - BLENDWIDTH, 0, BLENDWIDTH, ClientHeight, bk2.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, BLENDWIDTH, ClientHeight, bf);
    finally
      bk2.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm5.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Invalidate;
end;

end.
```

[image: Screenshot]

[Compiled demo EXE](https://privat.rejbrand.se/fadestr2.exe)

[Sample background bitmap](https://privat.rejbrand.se/fadestrbk.bmp)

Comment: WOW, PERFECT! Thank you for this great answer! BTW, do you think the `CopyParentImage` idea is good? and is this function looks ok?

Comment: @Vlad Your CopyParentImage is overkill. At entering your component's overriden Paint method, the "empty" canvas already hás the "parent image". Just copy it, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20590961/757830).

Comment: +1 I couldn't get it working with any combination of BitBlt, AlphaBlend, MaskBlt, MakeROP4, custom ternary raster-operation codes, etc...

Answer (score 5):

Hereby [Andreas' code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20583502/757830) (votes should be for him!) incorporated into a stand alone component:

```
unit FadingTextControl;

interface

uses
  Classes, Controls, Windows, Graphics;

type
  TFadingTextControl = class(TGraphicControl)
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  published
    property Caption;
    property Font;
  end;

implementation

{ TFadingTextControl }

constructor TFadingTextControl.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  ControlStyle := ControlStyle - [csOpaque];
end;

procedure TFadingTextControl.Paint;
const
  FadeWidth = 100;
var
  R: TRect;
  Overlay: TBitmap;
  BlendFunc: TBlendFunction;

  procedure FadeOverlay;
  type
    PRGB32Array = ^TRGB32Array;
    TRGB32Array = packed array[0..MaxInt div SizeOf(TRGBQuad) - 1] of TRGBQuad;
  var
    W: Integer;
    Y: Integer;
    Line: PRGB32Array;
    X: Integer;
  begin
    Overlay.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
    W := Overlay.Width;
    for Y := 0 to Overlay.Height - 1 do
    begin
      Line := Overlay.ScanLine[Y];
      for X := 0 to W - 1 do
        with Line[X] do
        begin
          rgbReserved := Round(255 * X / W);
          rgbRed := rgbRed * rgbReserved div 255;
          rgbGreen := rgbGreen * rgbReserved div 255;
          rgbBlue := rgbBlue * rgbReserved div 255;
        end;
    end;
  end;

begin
  R := ClientRect;
  Canvas.Font.Assign(Font);
  Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
  if Canvas.TextWidth(Caption) <= Width then
    DrawText(Canvas.Handle, PChar(Caption), -1, R, DT_SINGLELINE or DT_VCENTER)
  else
  begin
    Overlay := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      Overlay.Width := FadeWidth;
      Overlay.Height := Height;
      BitBlt(Overlay.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, FadeWidth, Height, Canvas.Handle,
        Width - FadeWidth, 0, SRCCOPY);
      DrawText(Canvas.Handle, PChar(Caption), -1, R, DT_SINGLELINE or
        DT_VCENTER);
      FadeOverlay;
      BlendFunc.BlendOp := AC_SRC_OVER;
      BlendFunc.BlendFlags := 0;
      BlendFunc.SourceConstantAlpha := 255;
      BlendFunc.AlphaFormat := AC_SRC_ALPHA;
      AlphaBlend(Canvas.Handle, Width - FadeWidth, 0, FadeWidth, Height,
        Overlay.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, FadeWidth, Height, BlendFunc);
    finally
      Overlay.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thanks! +1 so this was not "a very simple task" after all! ;) (with 4 close votes). the only thing I changed in this code for now, is made a class property of "FadeWidth". I will also add an option for FadeBMToWhite beacouse it also looks cool.

Comment: BTW, your comment about *"empty" canvas already hás the "parent image"* applies only to TGraphicControl? Am I right? so if this was a TCustomControl I should have used the `CopyParentImage`?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. A TGraphicControl borrows its Canvas from the Parent, a TCustomControl has its own.