# Delphi GDI+ DrawString Transparent From Left and Right

Tags: delphi, gdi+

I have problem drawing text transparent from left and right like this example:
Image1:

[image]

What i have done so far:

```
var
  linGrBrush: TGPLinearGradientBrush;
  Text : String;
  x, y : Single;
Begin
  Graphics.Clear(0);
  linGrBrush := TGPLinearGradientBrush.Create(MakePoint(0, 0),
                  MakePoint(300, 0), MakeColor(0, 0, 0, 0), MakeColor(255, 255, 0, 0));
      linGrBrush.SetBlendTriangularShape(0.8);
      Text := 'Transparent Text From Left And Right';
      x:= 0;
      y:= 0;
      Graphics.DrawString(Text, Length(Text), Font, MakePoint(x, Y), linGrBrush);
```

Result:
Image2:

[image]

How can i fix this?

Comment: What happens if you change first parameter of second MakePoint?